# Lubuntu 14.10 Firefox does not start

Tags: lubuntu, firefox

I just set up Lubuntu 14.10 on my notebook and now Firefox only starts after rebooting for one time. Once it's closed, it won't open again. Calling Firefox from the terminal gives me

```
dori-fisch@dorifisch:~$ firefox

(process:2954): Glib-critical **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known bug. See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1160569 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=833117

If you have anything to contribute to that bug report (at a glance, the detail that it runs once and then doesn't again seems to be a new detail).

According to the comments, one possible workaround that worked for at least one user (but didn't work for at least one other user) is to set G_SLICE=always-malloc in the environment

To do that in just firefox, add this line to `~/.profile`:

```
$ G_SLICE=always-malloc firefox
```

You could also try to run firefox in Safe Mode and see if that changes anything.